# Freeing global variable

Tags: c, malloc, c99

Suppose I have a global variable that contains a large structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char Big[1024]
} LARGE;

static LARGE x;

void main()
{
     free(x);
}
```

Can I safely call free(x) from main when I dont need it anymore?

Comment: C doesn't have global variables. I believe you're referring to variables that have static storage duration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  You didn't dynamically allocate `x` so don't need to (and cannot) free it.

If you absolutely need to free the memory before your program exits, declare a pointer as global, allocate it on demand, using `malloc` or `calloc`, then `free` it when you're finished with the structure.

```
static LARGE* x;

void main()
{
    x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    // use x
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that you call sizeof(*x) instead of sizeof(LARGE) like im used to. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: The two are identical.  I just prefer `sizeof(*x)` as that's sure to remain correct as you refactor your code and change the type of `x`.

Comment: sizeof is not a function that's called, but an operator that's evaluated when it's part of an expression. In this case, sizeof *x == sizeof(*x).

Answer (score 4):

No, `free` can only be used to deallocate objects that have been allocated through a call to `malloc`.

Objects with static storage duration can only be deallocated when the program exits.